# Android - check if html code contains div with specified id

Tags: java, android, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I need to make sure that a certain website code contains a div like this one:

```
<div id="iframe-content"> some code here... </div>
```

I tried this way:

```js
elementTry = doc.select("div#iframe-content");
```

and next I stored it into the String

```
String someText;
someText = elementTry.toString();
```

and tried to show the output via Toast, but it gives me "null". I am sure the website contains the div with this id, so
what can I do to fix it?

EDIT:
Toast code

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Passed: "+ someText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Please post toast code that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
elementTry = doc.select("div#iframe-content");
String someText;
someText = elementTry.text();
```

Hope this helps